# What is the purpose of writing main logic of a function inside a block scope like React sourcecode?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, curly-braces

```
function createFactoryWithValidation(type) {
    var validatedFactory = createElementWithValidation.bind(null, type);
    validatedFactory.type = type;

    {
        if (!didWarnAboutDeprecatedCreateFactory) {
            didWarnAboutDeprecatedCreateFactory = true;

            warn('React.createFactory() is deprecated and will be removed in ' + 'a future major release. Consider using JSX ' + 'or use React.createElement() directly instead.');
        } // Legacy hook: remove it


        Object.defineProperty(validatedFactory, 'type', {
            enumerable: false,
            get: function () {
                warn('Factory.type is deprecated. Access the class directly ' + 'before passing it to createFactory.');

                Object.defineProperty(this, 'type', {
                    value: type
                });
                return type;
            }
        });
    }

    return validatedFactory;
}
```

Here is a sample function in React source and  I've never seen it before, so someone can explain the main purpose of writing the main logic inside a bracket pair? Thank you guys so much.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to do it here. In other cases one might want to create a scope for `let` or `const` declared variables.

Comment: In addition to what zerkms what saying, if you look at the latest source code, they seem to have removed the braces https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/4c7036e807fa18a3e21a5182983c7c0f05c5936e/packages/react/src/ReactElementValidator.js

Comment: Oh, It's seem be weird when they use this pattern without a clarified intention.